# How to dynamically call a method in Objective-C using an NSString or const char *name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm doing some work with dynamic programming in Objective-C and I've read through the Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide front to back and been able to do most of what I need, but the one thing I haven't figured out is how to call a method dynamically provided I have a string representation of it.

Essentially I dynamically do a property lookup to see if my object has a property that matches from a list using class_copyPropertyList and then loop through and match these via an NSMutableDictionary that is populated from a plist file. When a match is found I want to execute the property.  I have no way of knowing ahead of time what matches could possibly exist as this is a lib that will be packaged into many different apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `NSSelectorFromString` to create a `SEL` from an `NSString`. Then you can execute it using one of the `performSelector` methods.

**Setting a property dynamically:**

```
SEL setter = NSSelectorFromString(@"setProperty:");
[myObject performSelector:setter withObject:newValue];
```

**Getting a property dynamically:**

```
SEL getter = NSSelectorFromString(@"property");
id myProperty = [myObject performSelector:getter];
```

For more complicated methods you can use [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSMethodSignature`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
SEL action = NSSelectorFromString(@"someMethod:withArguments:");
NSMethodSignature *signature = [myObject methodSignatureForSelector:action];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setArgument:arg1 atIndex:2]; // indices 0 and 1 are reserved.
[invocation setArgument:arg2 atIndex:3];
[invocation invokeWithTarget:myObject];
id returnedObject;
[invocation1 getReturnValue:&returnedObject];
```

Comment: "if you are interested in the return value too" - you can do that with `performSelector:` too.

Comment: You should probably check if the property has a custom getter or setter first, rather than assuming they follow the name/setName pattern.  You can determine if and what these custom accessors are by groking the result of property_getAttributes().  See the relevant section in the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6)

Comment: I tried this out, and it works as I was hoping, but fails when the property type is a simple data type such as int rather than an actual class type.  Is there a way to deal with this as well, save from having to convert all primitive data types?

Answer (score 2):

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
[anObject performSelector:s];
```

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString